# Error con IF que contiene varios OR

Tags: python

Error al saltar de linea en las condiciones if que contiene or. Si escribo en una sola linea da bien, pero con saltos de linea mal. Es más legible con saltos de linea como en el ejemplo. ¿Por qué el error?

No da error:

```
if bot == "que tal" or bot == "qué tal" or bot == "que tal?":
```

Devuelve error:

```
if bot == "que tal"
or bot == "qué tal"
or bot == "que tal?":
```

Ejemplo devuelve error:

```
bot=""
while bot != "salir":
    bot= input("Dime Lo Que Quieras\n")
    if bot == "que tal"
    or bot == "qué tal"
    or bot == "que tal?":
        print("Bien, Gracias.")
    if bot == "que dia es hoy?"
    or bot == "¿que dia es hoy?"
    or bot == "que Dia Es Hóy": 
        print("Hoy Es 25")
    if bot == "tienes novia?"
    or bot == "¿tienes novia?":
        print("La respuesta es No")
```

Answer (score 2):

El carácter de continuación es "\":

```
if bot == "que tal" \
  or bot == "qué tal" \
   or bot == "que tal?":
```

El error es porque Python espera una instrucción por línea salvo en literales entrecomillado o que encuentre el carácter de continuación. Ojo que este carácter tiene algunas restricciones

Comment: ¿Hay manera de simplificar if bot == "que tal" or bot == "qué tal" or bot == "que tal?": ? Gracias.

Comment: @julian Sí, usa: `if bot in ("que tal", "qué tal", "que tal?"):`

Comment: Si podrías utilizar una expresión regular if re.search(r"que[eé] tal\??",bot) si bot no tiene ninguna de las formas dará None. Esta expresión te cubre hasta el "qué tal?" que no está en tu lista.